# Posting HTML form to iframe causes problems with browser history

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, file-upload, form-submit

I have an HTML form that contains regular inputs as well as a file input. When a user selects one or more files to upload, I instantly change the `target` attribute of the form to the `name` attribute of a hidden iframe on the page as well as change the `action` attribute of the form to the script that I want to send the file-upload request to.

From the requested script, I then upload the files to the server, and once the script ends, the `onload` event for the iframe fires, after which I make various interface changes.

Everything uploads correctly, but the problem is that the iframe request seems to cause a page request to be added to the browser history, which creates unintended consequences. I have currently found the following two issues:

1. If I upload one file and then right after that another file, and then
   hit the Back button, the browser stays on the form instead of going
   back to the page displayed before the form.
2. If I upload one file and then hit the
   Back button, the browser corrects goes back to the previous page,
   but if I then hit the Forward button to go back to the form, for
   whatever reason, the script that is executed in the iframe to upload the files is immediately called upon the form loading, which causes other unintended side effects.

Point being, it seems like the iframe request being added to the browser history is causing all sorts of problems, and I'd like to avoid this if possible. Is there any way to stop this all from happening?

I should also note that I'm currently only developing in the most recent version of Chrome, but whatever solution I use must work back to IE8.

Answer (score 2):

**Below are some explaining refer to your bug**

- [Rerendering components with iframe leads to browser history duplicates](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6259)

  > The navigation events of the iframe (change its src attribute in this case) are propagated up to the parent window as well.
- Here is a full demo and explaining of this weird bug. [Back Button Behavior on a Page With an iframe](http://www.webdeveasy.com/back-button-behavior-on-a-page-with-an-iframe/)
- [3-reasons-why-you-should-not-use-iframes](https://enrega.com.au/websites/insights/3-reasons-why-you-should-not-use-iframes)

  > Reason #2: iFrames cause usability issues
  >   The iFrame tag is notorious for creating usability annoyances. Among most common of them are:
  >
  > ```
  > * it tends to break the "Back" button in the browser being used;
  > * it confuses visually impaired visitors, using screen readers;
  > * it confuses users, suddenly opening the iframe content in a new browser window;
  > * content within the iframe doesn't fit in and looks odd because it can ignore the styles sheets from within the main website;
  > * content within the iframe is missing since the source URL changed; and,
  > * navigation of the site in the iframe stops working.
  > ```

Comment: I now use XHR2 and FormData for all form uploads, so this is no longer an issue, but it used to be for when clients wanted dynamic file uploads in IE8, etc.

Comment: This bug is all about browser history behavior of using form and iframe. Nowadays even in the React project, it's still a problem when you refresh an iframe in pages,  yep, that's how I encounter it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem and a solution. The problem was that I had an iframe on the form page when the form was first loaded and somehow (I don't know why) that was causing the problem described above.

However, I decided to remove the iframe from page-load, and instead dynamically create an iframe via JS when it was time to upload files. Once the files were uploaded and the iframe `onload` event fired, I then removed the iframe from the DOM via JS and it no longer caused the problem occurring above.

I'm honestly not too sure why that fixed the problem or if it's just a potential issue with browsers, but all the same, for anyone that wants to use an iframe to upload files on a form without reloading the page, be sure to not have the iframe on the page when it first loads, and instead dynamically add the iframe only when you need it and remove it when you're done.